# Move constructor and initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, unordered-map, move-semantics

I want to implement move constructors (no copy constructor) for a certain type that needs to be a value type in a `boost::unordered_map`. Let's call this type `Composite`.

`Composite` has the following signature:

```
struct Base
{
  Base(..stuff, no default ctor) : initialization list {}
  Base(Base&& other) : initialization list {} 
}

struct Composite
{
  Base member;
  Composite(..stuff, no default ctor) : member(...) {}
  Composite(Composite&& other) : member(other.member) {} // <---- I want to make sure this invokes the move ctor of Base
}
```

I want to write this so `boost::unordered_map< Key , Composite >` does not require the copy constructor, and just uses the move constructor. If possible, I don't want to use the copy constructor of `Base` in the initialization list of move constructor of `Composite`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Say `member(std::move(other.member))`.

As a golden rule, whenever you take something by rvalue reference, you need to use it inside `std::move`, and whenever you take something by universal reference (i.e. deduced templated type with `&&`), you need to use it inside `std::forward`.

Comment: +1 for a good use of the relatively new term *universal reference*.

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin: That term was contrived on the spot by Scott Meyers. The standards committee prefers the term "forwarding reference" nowadays.

Comment: We're almost two years in now, glad to see that the community has converged on a stable term.