# C++: std::move with rvalue reference is not moving contents

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

Sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
void print(const T& _vec)
    {        
        for( auto c: _vec )
            std::cout << c << ",";
    }

typedef std::vector<std::string> vecstr_t;

struct Trade
{
    explicit Trade(vecstr_t&& vec) : _vec(vec )
    {       
    }  

     vecstr_t _vec;
};


int main()
{   
    vecstr_t tmpV = {"ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR"};    
    std::cout << "size 1:" << tmpV.size() << "\t"; print(tmpV); std::cout <<  "\n" ;    
    Trade t(std::move(tmpV));    
    std::cout << "size 2:" << tmpV.size() << "\t";  print(tmpV); std::cout <<  "\n" ; // expted tmpV should be e,pty but it has original contents    
    print(t._vec);    
}
```

I expect size 2: should be ZERO but output is:

```
size 1:4    ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,
size 2:4    ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,
ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,
```

Comment: Evaluation of tmpV after move is unrefined

Comment: You have just copied ( to be more precise initialized member of structure Trade in initializer list ) the vector from rvalue as far I understand, move constructor is good for passing ownership of object ..., in this case it is simple copy

Comment: `_vec(std::move(vec))`. If it has a name, it's an lvalue. Also, you can't expect `size 2` to be anything. A moved-from vector is in a valid but unspecified state.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
explicit Trade(vecstr_t&& vec) : _vec(vec)
{}
```

In the constructor above, even though `vec` is of type *rvalue reference to `vecstr_t`*, it is itself an lvalue. The basic rule to remember is - [if it has a name, it's an lvalue](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html).

There are very few contexts where an lvalue may automatically be moved from (such as the return statement of a function that returns an object by value), but a constructor's *mem-initializer* list is not one of them.

In your example, `_vec` is copy constructed from `vec`. If you want it to be move constructed instead, use `std::move`.

```
explicit Trade(vecstr_t&& vec) : _vec(std::move(vec))
{}
```

Now the second call to `print` will not print anything. Note that technically the second call could print a non-zero size because the contents of a moved from `vector` are unspecified. But on most (probably all) implementations, you'll see an empty `vector`.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cf7efe1f78fe0ec)

---

Your comment below says your intent is to accept both rvalues and lvalues, move only in the case of the former, and copy the argument otherwise. As currently written, your constructor will only accept rvalues, and not lvalues. There are a few different options to achieve what you want.

The easiest probably is to change the parameter so that it's taking the argument by value, and then unconditionally move.

```
explicit Trade(vecstr_t vec) : _vec(std::move(vec))
{}
```

The drawback with this approach is that you may incur an additional move construction of the `vector`, but move constructing a `vector` is cheap, and you should go with this option in most cases.

The second option is to create two overloads of the constructor

```
explicit Trade(vecstr_t&&      vec) : _vec(std::move(vec)) {}
explicit Trade(vecstr_t const& vec) : _vec(vec)            {}
```

The drawback with this one is that the number of overloads will increase exponentially as the number of constructor arguments increases.

The third option is to use perfect forwarding.

```
template<typename V>
explicit Trade(V&& vec) : _vec(std::forward<V>(vec)) {}
```

The code above will preserve the value category of the argument passed to the constructor when it forwards it to construct `_vec`. This means that if `vec` is an rvalue, the `vecstr_t` move constructor will be called. And if it is an lvalue, it will be copied from.

The drawback with this solution is that your constructor will accept any type of argument, not just a `vecstr_t`, and then the move/copy construction in the mem-initializer list will fail if the argument is not convertible to `vecstr_t`. This may result in error messages that are confusing to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My intention is in Trade constructor if { Trade(vecstr_t&& vec) } - if rvalue is passed then _vec should be created using move c'tor but if lvalue is passed then _vec should be created from copy c'tor. I don't want to explicitly move the vec but let it happen automatically based on rvalue or lvalue ref. Can we achieve this ?

Comment: Perfect ...I will go with 1st option as this class will be part of library used by other clients and I don't want all client to use std::move(lvalue) while invoking c'tor of Trade class.

Really appreciate your very clear explanation.

Comment: Perfect ...I like option 3 but I will go with 1st option as this class will be part of library used by other clients and I don't want all client to use std::move(lvalue) while invoking c'tor of Trade class. Really appreciate your very clear explanation