# Pointer is breaks when inserting to vector

Tags: c++

I have a problem when inserting a new value to a vector, the pointer stops working correctly. Here is my code:

Cell.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Cell
{
public:
    Cell(std::string s) : s(s) {}

    std::string s;
    void test() {}
    std::vector<Cell*> refs;
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "Cell.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<Cell> cells = {Cell("1"), Cell("2"), Cell("3")};
    cells[2].refs.push_back(&cells[0]);

    std::string val = cells[2].refs[0]->s;

    cells.insert(cells.begin() + 1, Cell("4"));

    val = cells[3].refs[0]->s; // exception
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I am inserting Cell("4"), my pointer breaks and give me an access violation exception. Can you tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: Pointers into `cells` are invalidated when you reach `cells.insert(...)`

Comment: Consider using [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)

Comment: Side-note: `Cell(std::string s) : s(s) {}` should be `Cell(std::string s) : s{std::move{s}} {}` to avoid a copy. See also [Is std::move really needed on initialization list of constructor for heavy members passed by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23929800/11082165)

Comment: @Brian61354270 ok, I'll try this

Comment: @Brian61354270 Yes, this works. Thanks for the help. And thanks for the tip about the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
cells.insert(cells.begin() + 1, Cell("4"));
```

If `insert()` results in the vector reallocating its contents, all existing pointers and iterators to any value in the vector are no longer valid.

```
cells[2].refs.push_back(&cells[0]);
```

Such as this one, `&cells[0]`. If `insert()` reallocates `cells`, this `&cells[0]` pointer is no longer valid, and this becomes undefined behavior.